# Does SharePoint Spell Check only show the spelling errors?

Tags: spellchecker

I am using SharePoint 2013. I noticed that the spell check allows SharePoint to count the number of spelling errors in my Linked List. However, it does not offer a word alternative. Is this something that the SharePoint Admin must enable, or is this as far as the Spell Check will go?

Thanks

[image: SharePoint Spell Check Image]

Comment: I did as stated above, but I still get the same error anyway (it doesn't fix the spelling mistake) in Microsoft Edge. It will fix it if it's in IE though. Any reason why spell check doesn't work on Microsoft Edge (SharePoint 2016 on-prem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is this something that the SharePoint Admin must enable?**

No,  it does not need  an additional configuration ,

Once you click on Spelling button, you will get the number of errors as you mentioned on your question , and to offer a word alternative , You should click on `Spelling error found` to can get the suggestion.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did find that the spellcheck works in the Notes section and not the Type the description area.

Comment: You are welcome , and I am sorry I was not here , regarding spell check it should work with the fields with data type text and multi-text and not work with the URL field , and the description in this case is a part of URL field . please don't hesitate to tell me if you need more clarification .